# Is it possible to connect the Azure Sql database on Mono project consisting of C #?

Tags: c#, azure, mono, azure-sql-database

I developing mono project C# console application, I need to connect Azure Sql database service.
I make this code, This occurs Exception "NotImplement Exception".
I try to find solution. but Yet it did not implement SSL Encryption.
Did this fix the problem now?

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Mono.Security;
namespace AzureConsoleApplication
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine ("Hello World!");

            string connectionString = "Server=tcp:Server.database.windows.net,1433;Database=TestDatabase;" +
            "User ID=ID@Servername;Password=password;" +
            "Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=true;Connection Timeout=30;";
            IDbConnection dbcon;
            using (dbcon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                dbcon.Open ();
                using (IDbCommand dbcmd = dbcon.CreateCommand())
                {
                    string sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable1;";
                    dbcmd.CommandText = sql;
                    using (IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            string first = (string)reader ["ID"];
                            string twice = (string)reader ["Col1"];
                            Console.WriteLine ("ID : " + first + "Col1 : " + twice);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Last I checked Mono does not support SSL for connecting to a SQL database.

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Data/System.Data.SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs#L765

It's a gross hack, but at my current company we created a linked server on a local SQL server and then made our database calls route through that.

What's funny is that the SQL client for node.js does support SSL. =)

Comment: I'd run whole stuff in a docker container bridging TLS with stunnel.